# Knex - Result of SUM queries between knex and mysql workbench return different values

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am currently facing this issue when summing fields. I am using Knex and Mysql.

When using Knex, I get this result for the LastYr column..

Knex Result:

[image: Knex Result]

But doing the same query in Mysql Workbench, I get this (which is what I want)

Mysql Workbench:

[image: Mysql Workbench]

My query is this:

```
SELECT t1.*, IFNULL(t2.TotalUnits,0) AS TotalUnits, ROUND(IFNULL(t2.totalRevenue,0),0) AS TotalRevenue FROM (SELECT BranchDept, ForPeriod, SUM(SysGen) AS Gen, SUM(UserInput) as Live, SUM(PrevYear) AS LastYr, SUM(SysGen) - SUM(UserInput) AS Input FROM tbl_demand_forecast_details WHERE BranchDept='" + req.body.branchdept + "' AND ForPeriod >= '" + fystart + "' " +
        "AND ForPeriod <= '" + fyend + "' GROUP BY BranchDept, ForPeriod " +
        "ORDER BY ForPeriod) AS t1 " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN " +
        "(SELECT BranchDept, AsOfPeriod, SUM(UnitSales) AS totalUnits, SUM(PesoSales) AS totalRevenue FROM tbl_sales_history " + 
        "WHERE BranchDept='" + req.body.branchdept + "' AND AsOfPeriod >= '" + fystart + "' AND AsOfPeriod <= '" + fyend + "' GROUP BY AsOfPeriod) AS t2 " +
        "ON t1.BranchDept = t2.BranchDept AND t1.ForPeriod = t2.AsOfPeriod
```

It seems knex is adding the previous value to the next in the LastYr column.
I tried this with knex.raw and using the knex methods, and I still get the wrong values.

This is driving me nuts for the past two days. Anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I finally got it.

The SUM query goes haywire when there are null values on the column being summed. Replacing those with zeroes fixed this issue.